# Is there a way to validate a Sizzle selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

Is there a way to validate (verify that its constructed correctly) a Sizzle selector without running it?

Comment: What is an example of an incorrectly constructed selector?

Comment: ehhh you can check it in a javascript console

Comment: @roatin: `##` or `a[` or `.` or lots of other strings.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? if your worried about speed what about just suppling an empty context $(selector, emptyContext).

Comment: @Roatin: Anything that doesn't match the grammar for the language: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar

Comment: Can you please clarify why you need this? I'm curious

Comment: Is `:animated` valid? `:header`? `:eq()`? They're not valid css3 selectors (i.e. not defined behaviour by spec), but they are valid sizzle selectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as Russ says, since Sizzle interprets the selector, it cannot validate it without evaluating it.

However, you can catch the exception thrown by Sizzle to determine if a selector is valid or not:

```
function isSelectorValid(selector)
{
    try {
        $(selector);
    } catch (x) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your can test this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LfKNc/2/).

---

**EDIT:** For the sake of history, my original (and overengineered) answer was:

However, it's possible to temporarily override Sizzle's error management in order to extract a boolean value from the error status of its last parse operation. The following solution takes advantage of the fact that jQuery exposes Sizzle through `$.find` (so far):

```
function isSelectorValid(selector)
{
    var oldErrorMethod = $.find.error;
    try {
        $.find.error = function(msg) {
            valid = false;
            oldErrorMethod(msg);
        };
        $(selector);
        return true;
    } catch (x) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        $.find.error = oldErrorMethod;
    }
}
```

That can arguably be considered as a horrible hack, but it works: you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LfKNc/1/).

Comment: You could also just `return false` in the `catch` block.

Comment: @SLaks, excellent point! I'll update my answer right away, thanks :)

Comment: @SLaks, you're absolutely right, I guess I got completely carried away. Answer amended, now I think I'll carry myself away from the computer for a bit. Thanks again for the heads-up :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer - complete with jsfiddle! It hadn't occurred to me that Sizzle would raise an error on bad selectors (as it should). I think I have got accustomed to jQuery silently failing on things (which I don't like).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, the Sizzle engine isn't compiled so the only way to check the validity of the selector is to select it.

However, you can do something like this:

```
var selector = ...construct your selector ...
if ($(selector).length > 0) {
 // it worked.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't distinguish a selector which does not match the [grammar for selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar) from a valid selector which is valid, yet matches no elements.